# What is the appropriate question tag for sentences such as "Neither of you is..."?

Tags: grammatical-number, questions, question-tags

**Neither of you is going to the show tonight, *_*___?**

Should it be **isn't he/she?** I think the fact that **neither of you** takes the third-person singular verb **is** means that a third-person question tag ought to be used. But it sounds so awfully strange. So does the second-person alternative **aren't you?** You can trivially replace all question tags with **right?** in informal speech, but aside from that, what is the appropriate question tag to use in such sentences?

EDIT: Oh right, I should have realized that. How careless of me. But can you explain why you would use "are you" instead of "isn't he/she", even though "neither of you" is a third-person reference?

Comment: There are any number of "grammar nazis" insisting that *"neither"* is singlular, but I think they are simply wrong. In this context it makes much more sense to say *"Neither of you are going, are you?"*.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you asking that's any different to the ground covered by the question I linked to?

Comment: But "neither of you" would still be a third-person reference, so the question would simply change to whether "aren't you?" or "aren't they?" ought to be used. Still not something that has been asked.

Comment: No it's not - *Neither of you* is second person plural in this construction. I also don't understand why you keep wanting to place your "repetitious/confirmatory clause" in the negative. The standard phrasing is as I've given it above.

Comment: Just careless of me.

Comment: I still don't understand. Careless to keep phrasing the confirmatory rejoinder in the negative, or careless not to have realised that the issue only arises in the first place because you didn't want to use "are" as the first verb?

Comment: The former. But I suppose I'm convinced now that considering "neither of you" a second-person reference simplifies things.

Comment: Yeah, well it's only my opinion, of course, but I think "neither of" can be either singular or plural according to context/personal taste. Choosing to make it plural here seems "natural" (after all, you're talking to more than one person), and it certainly simplifies anything else you want to say afterwards!

Comment: @FumbleFingers ***Neither’s singularity/plurality is not a matter of taste, but of grammar.*** *Neither* can be plural when the nearer of the two disjuncts is plural: *Neither your mother nor your brothers **are** here* VS *Neither your brothers nor your mother **is** here.*  But I would just say “Neither of you is going to the show tonight, ***eh***?” myself.  You could use “... ***right***?” as well.

Comment: @tchrist: Rubbish. Horace Walpole: ["neither you nor your brother are quite well"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22neither+you+nor+your+brother+are+quite%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I think it's fair to say Walpole is considered a "man of letters". If you think that's too old, are you going to trash F Scott Fitzgerald too? ["Splendid is the one thing that neither you nor I are"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22thing+that+neither+you+nor+I+are%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). You write of "rules"; I write of what competent writers *write*.

Comment: (don't take me amiss. I like a good sparring partner! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Walpole strikes my native-speaker ear as completely a/un/anti-grammatical, and I could never generate such a sentence. The Fitzgerald has interference from "I’m good enough, aren’t I?"

Comment: @tchrist: You're clutching at straws. I only picked those two because they were universally-respected writers that were easy to find. *Rules of grammar* simply don't apply at this level. If you don't like Walpole's phrasing perhaps you just haven't read enough to get used to the full gamut of what competent writers are comfortable with. I wouldn't *mind* if he'd used the singular, but I certainly wouldn't start quoting "grammar" at one of the men who's been instrumental in defining it for later generations.

Comment: Similar: [One of us is wrong, aren't we?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178565)

Comment: @FumbleFingers _Neither of you_ can never be second person, singular or plural. _Neither_ is third person. Using a plural verb is indeed possible (despite the adamant misconception that is must always be singular), but it remains third person. Just like in the question linked to by sumelic, this is one case where tag question grammar simply breaks down. “Neither of you is/are going, are you?” is utterly ungrammatical to many (including me). “… is he?” is grammatical and natural if both people in ‘you’ are male—otherwise there is no possible tag question available at all.

Answer (score 4):

The correct tag would be *are you?*

> Neither of you is going to the show tonight, ***are you***?

Note that the main part of the sentence is implicitly negative, because of ***neither***, which explains the choice of **are you?** over **aren't you?**

Answer (score 2):

*Neither of you is going to the show* equates to *You are not going to the show. And you are not going either.* The correct tag for these equivalent sentences is *are you* and I would suggest this is the correct tag to your original statement: *Neither of you is going to the show, are you?*

Comment: But they're not completely equivalent, as evidenced by the fact that "neither of you" and "you" don't agree in number - the former taking the third-person singular verb "is", and the latter taking the second-person verb "are". So shouldn't one  analyze such sentences on a case-by-case basis, and establish that "are you?" is appropriate for "Neither of you is..." for some reason other than that it is appropriate for "You are not..."?

Comment: Sorry, but I suppose the main issue here is that the question tag doesn't agree with the number or person of the subject. That's what has me so confused. Thanks for the answer, though. I will agree that "are you?" sounds the least awkward of the possibilities.

Comment: @Kaiser Octavius, I agree that there is a mismatch between the singular *is* in the main clause and the plural *are* in the tag. But the speaker is addressing two people and the *you* of the main clause overrides the singular verb.  Sometimes language usage is pragmatic rather than based on strict grammatical logic. This explains, for example, why *neither of you are ..* is common in informal english.

Answer (score 2):

Tag questions don't always follow the simple agreement rules. For one thing, they can occur in sentences that have undergone some strange syntax, like *There*-insertion.

I have an [exercise on Tag Question Formation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf) for my English grammar classes; it's designed for native English speakers, who can fill in the blanks automatically. However, then they have to figure out how the rule works, and that's by no means obvious.

One thing that can help is that any Noun Phrase like *"X of T"* can usually be analyzed

***either***

- as a NP *X* modified by a prepositional phrase *of T* (so the verb agrees with *X*)

***or***

- as a quantifier *X (of)* modifying a NP *T* (so the verb agrees with *T*).

Comment: But surely in OP's particular case one would "think ahead", foresee the problem if you started with *"Neither of you is..."*, and switch to *"are"*? If you weren't quick enough to do that, wouldn't you just forget about the "tag question"? I can't see any sensible way of doing it if you used the singular verb, which in any case you shouldn't have wanted to do because you're *asking two people*, not *making a statement about each one as an individual*.

Answer (score 2):

According to *CGEL, neither of you* is a partitive construction, and *you* is called the partitive oblique. It mentions cases in which "the antecedent is construed as plural with respect to subject-verb agreement. Here the pronoun takes its person and number from the partitive oblique. But also includes cases in which "the antecedent takes a 3rd person singular verb but a 1st or 2nd person plural pronoun," but opines, "many will feel that this difference makes the construction less than fully felicitous (and would feel more comfortable with a plural verb), but for others it is acceptable and explicable in terms of the potentially more mechanical nature of subject-verb agreement."