# 'Someone' Singular or Plural?

Tags: verbs, pronouns, conjunctions

As we know, when the pronoun *someone* is used, the succeeding verb will be conjugated in the 3rd-person singular. Thus, the following sentence demonstrates legal usage:

> I cannot enter the room; someone **is** cooking.

However, note the following sentence:

> I cannot enter the room; someone **is** cooking, **are they** not?

As can be seen in the second sentence, when a question tag is used, it doesn't use the corresponding conjugation of the 3rd-person *singular* previously used, but rather, it takes on the 3rd-person *plural*. Why is this the case? What is more, why is the following sentence illegal?

> I cannot enter the room; someone **are** cooking, **are** they not?

I thank you, in advance, for your responses.

Comment: An answer to the question is [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered at 'Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?' etc.

Comment: How does that make it off-topic? It just makes it a potential duplicate (arguably)

Comment: I think this was closed against the wrong "duplicate". It should have been [*One of us is wrong, **aren't we**?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178565/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Someone" (as well as "anyone", "everyone", "no-one") takes the **singular** form ([example source](http://www.englishplus.com/grammar/00000027.htm)). This is why

> I cannot enter the room; someone is cooking

is correct but

> I cannot enter the room; someone are cooking

is not.

However, "someone" is *gender-neutral*, and so when that "someone" is referred to by a *personal* pronoun, "they" (taking the plural form) is used instead of "he" or "she", because "they" is the most commonly used gender-neutral pronoun - see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/87724).

Comment: It's probably the most commonly used gender-neutral pronoun because it's been covered on ELU so often.