# Is "someone" singular or plural? Why using "their" next to someone?

Tags: singular-they

I found this sentence as a definition for a word in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-round):

"To visit **someone** in **their** home"

But I've looked up the word **someone** and [I found that it is singular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288760/someone-singular-or-plural), so my question is:

Why is **"someone"** used in the sentence above with **their** and NOT with **his/her**?

---

**Update #1**

I've seen the link [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/435492) and found about "singular they", but I'm not sure if that is the answer for my question. Please, can someone tell me if the "singular they" is the reason it's used "their" with "someone"?

Comment: Singular *they* is indeed the reason that *their* is used with *someone*. English speakers have been using singular *they* with *someone* for centuries (unlike its use for non-binary people, which is much more recent). [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everybody+had+his%2Ceverybody+had+their&year_start=1820&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Comment: It can be his or her. But "their" and "they" is sex neutral. "Everyone should bring **their sneakers** to school tomorrow.